# Sorting the hash key by taking a subset in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

Is there any way to sort the hash key by taking only a subset  (last two chars) of it?

Eg:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'OCT12' => 1,
      'JAN13' => 4,
      'JAN14' => 39,
      'SRF14' => 1,
      'OCN13' => 64,
      'SBF14' => 80,
      'DEC13' => 22,
};
```

I am expecting to get the output: "OCT12","JAN13","OCN13","DEC13","JAN14","SRF14".

Cheers,
Jose

Comment: You cannot "sort the hash key".  You can sort an array, which you can get from `keys %hash`.

Comment: Also, because hashes don't have an order, there's no predicting the order of duplicate keys (e.g. JAN13, OCN13, & DEC13 could be listed in any order).

Comment: @cjm There are no duplicate keys in Hashes.

Comment: How should keys with the same numeric suffix be ordered? (I assume this is what cjm means by duplicate keys, @HunterMcMillen)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, I thought the example made clear I was referring to duplicates in the subset he wants to sort by.  There are 3 "13" keys and 3 "14" keys.

Comment: @cjm You could always sort by the first 3 chars if the last 2 are equal, `sort { substr($a, -2) cmp substr($b, -2) || substr($a, 0, 2) cmp substr($b, 0, 2) } keys(%hash)`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, except that his expected output seems to indicate he wants them to stay in the same order they were in the hash initialization (which is of course lost when the hash is created).  (And SBF14 disappeared.)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, That would be `substr($a, 0, 3)`, or better yet `substr($a, 0, -2)`, or better yet just `$a`.

Answer (score 6):

```
sort { substr($a, -2) cmp substr($b, -2) } keys(%$VAR1)
```

If you wanted to break ties by sorting by the first part,

```
sort { substr($a, -2) cmp substr($b, -2) || $a cmp $b } keys(%$VAR1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
my @sorted_keys = 
  map $_->[0],
  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
  map [$_, /(\d+)$/],
  keys %h;
```